# How to read session variables from bootstrap.php file

Tags: session, cakephp-2.0, croogo

Is there any any way to read session from bootstrap file.

```
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
$value = CakeSession::read('User.id');
```

I tried this code. But fail to read. Please help me out ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

rather than do all the initialisation overhead, I would here (and just here in bootstrap.php) resort to a basic php stuff:

```
session_start();
debug($_SESSION);
```

Comment: `CakeSession object` and `php $_SESSION` are two different things

Comment: Where do you see the main differences? cf https://api.cakephp.org/2.8/source-class-CakeSession.html#392

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors,

Looking for `Cakesession object` in `bootstrap.php` is a little weird but if you really must do it, do it this way:

```
App::import('Model/Datasource', 'CakeSession');
$Session = new CakeSession();
// $userId = $Session->read("Auth.User.id");
```

Check the difference between `App::uses()` (attempted by OP) and `App::import()` in documentation.